# How to load a pixel struct into an SSE register?

Tags: c, pixel, x86-64, sse, intrinsics

I have a struct of 8-bit pixel data:

```
struct __attribute__((aligned(4))) pixels {
    char r;
    char g;
    char b;
    char a;
}
```

I want to use SSE instructions to calculate certain things on these pixels (namely, a Paeth transformation). How can I load these pixels into an SSE register as 32-bits unsigned integers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Unpacking unsigned pixels with SSE2

Ok, using SSE2 integer intrinsics from `<emmintrin.h>` first load the thing into the lower 32 bits of the register:

```
__m128i xmm0 = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(*(const int*)&pixel);
```

Then first unpack those 8-bit values into 16-bit values in the lower 64 bits of the register, interleaving them with 0s:

```
xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(xmm0, _mm_setzero_si128());
```

And again unpack those 16-bit values into 32-bit values:

```
xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(xmm0, _mm_setzero_si128());
```

You should now have each pixel as 32-bit integer in the respective 4 components of the SSE register.

---

#### Unpacking signed pixels with SSE2

I just read, that you want to get those values as 32-bit **signed** integers, though I wonder what sense a signed pixel in [-127,127] makes. But if your pixel values can indeed be negative, the interleaving with zeros won't work, since it makes a negative 8-bit number into a positive 16-bit number (thus interprets your numbers as unsigned pixel values). A negative number has to be extended with `1`s instead of `0`s, but unfortunately that would have to be decided dynamically on a component by component basis, at which SSE is not that good.

What you could do is compare the values for negativity and use the resulting mask (which fortunately uses `1...1` for true and `0...0` for false) as interleavand, instead of the zero register:

```
xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(xmm0, _mm_cmplt_epi8(xmm0, _mm_setzero_si128()));
xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(xmm0, _mm_cmplt_epi16(xmm0, _mm_setzero_si128()));
```

This will properly extend negative numbers with `1`s and positives with `0`s. But of course this additional overhead (in the form of probably 2-4 additional SSE instructions) is only neccessary if your initial 8-bit pixel values can ever be negative, which I still doubt. But if this is really the case, you should rather consider `signed char` over `char`, as the latter has implementation-defined signedness (in the same way you should use `unsigned char` if those are the common unsigned [0,255] pixel values).

---

#### Alternative SSE2 unpacking using shifts

Although, as clarified, you don't need signed-8-bit to 32-bit conversion, but for the sake of completeness *harold* had another very good idea for the SSE2-based sign-extension, instead of using the above mentioned comparison based version. We first unpack the 8-bit values into the upper byte of the 32-bit values instead of the lower byte. Since we don't care for the lower parts, we just use the 8-bit values again, which frees us from the need for an extra zero-register and an additional move:

```
xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(xmm0, xmm0);
xmm0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(xmm0, xmm0);
```

Now we just need to perform and arithmetic right-shift of the upper byte into the lower byte, which does the proper sign-extension for negative values:

```
xmm0 = _mm_srai_epi32(xmm0, 24);
```

This should be more instruction count and register efficient than my above SSE2-version.

And as it should even be equal in instruction count for a single pixel (though 1 more instruction when amortized over many pixels) and more register efficient (due to no extra zero-register) compared to the above zero-extension, it might even be used for the unsigned-to-signed conversion if registers are rare, but then with a logical shift (`_mm_srli_epi32`) instead of an arithmetic shift.

---

#### Improved unpacking with SSE4

Thanks to *harold*'s comment, there is even a better option for the first 8-to-32 transformation. If you have SSE4 support (SSE4.1 to be precise), which has instructions for doing the complete conversion from 4 packed 8-bit values in the lower 32 bits of the register into 4 32-bit values in the whole register, both for signed and unsigned 8-bit values:

```
xmm0 = _mm_cvtepu8_epi32(xmm0);   //or _mm_cvtepi8_epi32 for signed 8-bit values
```

---

#### Packing pixels with SSE2

As for the follow-up of reversing this transformation, first we pack the signed 32-bit integers into signed 16-bit integers and saturating:

```
xmm0 = _mm_packs_epi32(xmm0, xmm0);
```

Then we pack those 16-bit values into unsigned 8-bit values using saturation:

```
xmm0 = _mm_packus_epi16(xmm0, xmm0);
```

We can then finally take our pixel from the lower 32-bits of the register:

```
*(int*)&pixel = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(xmm0);
```

Due to the saturation, this whole process will autmatically map any negative values to `0` and any values greater than `255` to `255`, which is usually intended when working with color pixels.

If you actually need truncation instead of saturation when packing the 32-bit values back into `unsigned char`s, then you will need to do this yourself, since SSE only provides saturating packing instructions. But this can be achieved by doing a simple:

```
xmm0 = _mm_and_si128(xmm0, _mm_set1_epi32(0xFF));
```

right before the above packing procedure. This should amount to just 2 additional SSE instructions, or only 1 additional instruction when amortized over many pixels.

Comment: My pixels are unsigned. I need to map them to the range [0..255] in those signed integers.

Comment: @FUZxxl Ok, then the first solution will work perfectly (have used it, too for the exact same purpose). But like said, consider using `unsigned char`s instead of `char`s then.

Comment: Thank you! BTW, do you also know, how to undo that transformation?

Comment: Thank you! For my application, I don't need saturation though. Is there a solution that uses truncation instead?

Comment: @FUZxxl No, I don't think so. But if your values are never out of `[0,255]`, then it doesn't make a difference (and if they are, I don't think truncation is a good idea), the saturation doesn't really cost anything. It's just a single SSE processor instruction, (like most other intrinsics), no matter if saturating or truncating. But since those instructions are actually provided with audio and video processing in mind, the saturation makes most sense and they didn't bother to provide non-saturating conversions, I think.

Comment: uff... Problem is, that I *really* need truncation. The file format is defined this way: *original_pixel = (transformed_pixel + predictor) & 0xff*, where the predictor is what I generate beforehand.

Comment: `_mm_ cvtepi8_epi32` can be useful here. Or you could unpack into the high bytes of words and then into the high words of dwords and then signed-shift right by 24.

Comment: @harold Thanks, didn't know about `_mm_cvtepi8_epi32` (it's SSE4, isn't it?). But unfortunately his initial pixel values are unsiged and this instruction would incorrectly sign-extend numbers larger than 127. But for the signed-to-signed conversion it's a good idea (as well as your signed-shift idea). Oh, there seems even to be an unsigned version `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32`.

Comment: @FUZxxl I added *harold*'s suggestions using SSE4 instructions to the answer, which require even less instructions (but on the other hand need SSE4 support). I also added his very good idea for SSE2-based signed-to-signed conversion, even though you don't need it as your 8-bit values are always unsinged.

Comment: How would one pack `__m128i` which contains 16 `UINT8` pixels into 4 `__m128`?