# Reverse a string using SSE

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

How do we reverse a string using using SSE? this concept is new to me so please give me some information about it. The reason is because someone says using SSE will fasten up the code and run-time.

I have searched for SSE which is _mm128 but don't really know how to factorize them.

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the following question but you could get some help with making a start on this by reading [Extracting SSE shuffled 32 bit value with only SSE2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474170/extracting-sse-shuffled-32-bit-value-with-only-sse2).

Comment: What version of SSE ?

Answer (score 4):

If you can assume a minimum of SSSE3 then it's very easy using `_mm_shuffle_epi8`, but before you do this you should really make sure that (a) your current implementation is a performance bottleneck and (b) that you have done all you can to make the current implementation as fast as possible, since this is such a simple operation that its performance should really be limited only by memory bandwidth for any decent implementation.

Anyway, here is a simple implementation and test harness:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tmmintrin.h> // SSSE3

void reverse(char *begin, char *end)
{
    while (begin < end)
    {
        const char c = *begin;
        *begin = *end;
        *end = c;
        ++begin;
        --end;
    }
}

void vreverse(char *begin, char *end)
{
    const __m128i vrev = _mm_set_epi8(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

    ssize_t len = end - begin + 1;

    while (len >= 16)
    {
        __m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)begin);
        __m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)(end - 15));
        v1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v1, vrev);
        v2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(v2, vrev);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)(end - 15), v1);
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)begin, v2);
        begin += 16;
        end -= 16;
        len -= 32;
    }
    if (len > 1)
    {
        reverse(begin, end);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const size_t MAX_LEN = 64;
    char s1[MAX_LEN + 1], s2[MAX_LEN + 1];
    size_t i, len;

    for (len = 0; len < MAX_LEN; ++len)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            s1[i] = s2[i] = (char)('a' + rand() % 26);
        }
        s1[len] = s2[len] = '\0';
        reverse(s1, s1 + len - 1);
        vreverse(s2, s2 + len - 1);
        if (memcmp(s1, s2, len) != 0)
        {
            printf("FAIL: len = %zu\n", len);
            printf("FAIL: s1 = %s\n", s1);
            printf("FAIL: s2 = %s\n", s2);
        }
        else
        {
            //printf("PASS: len = %zu\n", len);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test it:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mssse3 -O3 vreverse.c && ./a.out
$
```