# "Extend" data type size in SSE register

Tags: c, sse, simd

I'm using VS2005 (at work) and need an SSE intrinsic that does the following:

I have a pre-existing `__m128i` *n* filled with 16 bit integers `a_1,a_2,....,a_8`.

Since some calculations that I now want to do require 32 instead of 16 bits, I want to extract the two four-sets of 16-bit integers from *n* and put them into two separated `__m128i`s which contain `a_1,...,a_4` and `a_5,...,a_8` respectively.

I could do this manually using the various `_mm_set` intrinsics, but those would result in eight `mov`s in assembly, and I'd hoped that there would be a faster way to do this.

Comment: Take as look at these [SSE4.1 intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/cpp-mac/GUID-C31E8AF7-77C8-4151-852B-C60849148E14.htm). You can get what you want by using two of those and an unpack/shuffle.

Comment: I don't think they're available in VS2005.

Comment: Eek... VS2005. Tell your boss to burn it... with fire. :)

Comment: Otherwise... You're stuck doing it the long way with a nasty mess of shuffles, shifts, and masks.

Comment: @Mystical It's not just "my boss".  We've had licences for all of the new Visual Studios for a long time (some smaller projects also use them), but various reasons keep us from switching everything over permanently. A lot of people have a lot of dependencies to VS2005 stuff (not just us either, also outside customers which use our APIs, so we couldn't for example switch to VS2012 and use C++11 stuff). Besides, VS2005 isn't that bad. I'd like to use more C++11 and when it comes to technicalities like this, it's annoying that it lacks features (or the profiler from VS12), but otherwise it's fine

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12121640/743214.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that I understand correctly what it that you want to achieve (unpack 8 x 16 bits in one vector into two vectors of 4 x 32 bit ints),  I typically do it like this in SSE2 and later:

```
__mm128i v = _mm_set_epi16(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);  // v = { 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }
__mm128i v_lo = _mm_srai_epi32(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(v, v), 16); // v_lo = { 3, 2, 1, 0 }
__mm128i v_hi = _mm_srai_epi32(_mm_unpackhi_epi16(v, v), 16); // v_hi = { 7, 6, 5, 4 }
```

Comment: Nice... This isn't as nasty as I had imagined. Granted I never tried very hard since I usually have access to SSE4.1.

Comment: But would this be faster than v_lo= _mm_set_epi32(a_1,...,a_4) v_hi = _mm_set_epi32(a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8)? I can access the single values via the __m128i intrinsic which seems to be a union where I can access the various contained data types like an array.

Comment: @TravisG Everything will be faster than using `_mm_set` and extracting individual components. What your code would do is take those values out of the SSE register into some aligned memory storage, do some non-SSE operations on each of them, then load this into the other register. This will be leagues slower than performing it all iside the SSE registers with a bunch of SEE ops. In general, accessing *single components* from SSE registers is a performance killer for any SSE code, no matter if your library makes this programmable easily by providing a union...

Comment: @TravisG ...It's not that you *only* loose SIMD parallelism. This whole single component access has to be backed by a bunch of memory operations, as SSE is not built for that.

Comment: @TravisG: in addition to Christian's valid comments, I'll just say that the code above, although it maybe looks nasty, translates to just 4 instructions. If you start messing with individual vector elements using scalar code then you'll be looking at way more than 4 instructions (plus all the other aforementioned problems).

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks!