# replace _mm_cvtepi16_epi32 using only SSE3

Tags: x86, sse, intrinsics

`_mm_cvtepi16_epi32` (`pmovsxwd`) requires SSE4.1

How can we sign-extend vector elements with only SSE3, or SSE2?

An SSSE3 answer might be interesting, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Extend" data type size in SSE register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724419/extend-data-type-size-in-sse-register).  I couldn't find that duplicate until I worked out the answer, so I could google on _mm_unpacklo_epi16 _mm_srai_epi32.  It didn't come up for "_mm_cvtepi16_epi32 without sse4.1", so this is not a bad question.  It's a duplicate, but not one I'd expect the OP to have found on his own.

Answer (score 4):

Duplicate each 16bit element (from the low half) with an unpack, then use an arithmetic right shift to leave a copy of the sign bit in the upper half of each 32b element.

```
__m128i v16 = ...;
v32 = _mm_unpacklo_epi16(v16, v16);  // [ a a b b c c d d ]
v32 = _mm_srai_epi32(v32, 16);
```

This is only SSE2.  This is two fast instructions, so I don't think there's anything to be gained from SSE3 or SSSE3, and can't think of anything.  The only thing that would be better than this would be a way to do it non-destructively (so the compiler doesn't have to copy `v16` if we still need it).

If you could already do it in one instruction, `pmovsxwd` might not have been introduced.  (Although it might have anyway for consistency with the other `pmovsx` forms.)  Where `pmovsx` really shines is when going from byte to dword, or byte to qword.  Also, the load form of it is nice, even though intrinsics make it really hard to use as a load<sup>1</sup>.

For other element sizes, there's a `psraw`, so 8->16 is also efficient, but there is no `psraq` (only logical left/right shifts for 64bit elements).  `pmovsxdq` is harder to emulate.  `pblendw` is also SSE4.1.  I'm thinking maybe unpack with zeros and then arithmetic right-shift that.  Then you can OR with a vector unpacked with zeros the other way.

This has the advantage of being able to use `_mm_unpackhi` to get the upper half, which `pmovsx`/`pmovzx` unfortunately don't do.

---

Footnote 1:  Performance of `_mm_cvtepi16_epi64` for example with a memory source is somewhat improved with recent compiler versions able to fold narrow load intrinsics like `_mm_load_ss` or `_mm_loadu_si32` into memory source operands for `pmovs/zx`, on GCC versions where they aren't buggy (strict aliasing safe, and for `_mm_loadu_si32` not shuffling the element to the top.